# bootstrap JavaScript not working as in when the screen size is decreased the menu bar wont work

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

so I'm working with Django for the first time and I am following a tutorial, bootstrap is used for the navbar so I added the CSS from bootstrap it worked but the JavaScript from bootstrap is not working, I know that because when the screen size is reduced, a menu bar appears instead of the  navbar items but it doesn't work when clicked. How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CRMain</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
</head>

<body>
    {% include "accounts/navbar.html"%}

    {% block content %}


    {% endblock %}

    <hr>
    <h5>footer</h5>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

2 screenshots of the before and after:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5he.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JteLC.png

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` won't validate outside of the `<body>` or `<head>` tags.

```
<html>
  ....
  <body>
     ....
     <script type="text/javascript" src="....."></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did that but it's still not working

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> Try this CDN

Comment: this code ruined the css do you have the specific css related to the js bootstrap you sent? so that they match

Comment: Yes..! I can't find any other issues in your HTML.. maybe the CDN doesn't work correctly.. so try to use CDN that is available in official doc of [bootstrap5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

Comment: will do, can you please send me the css file that corresponds to the javascript file you sent?

Comment: [click here!](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)